# How to make hte title and headers the same size as the text in Org mode?

Tags: org-mode, fonts

I have this in my Emacs:

[image]

I want the title and headers to be the same as the normal text. What should I put into my .spacemacs file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easiest achieved via the customization interface. You should remove (disable) the height attributes from the `org-document-title` and the `org-level-1,2,3...` faces. You navigate to the correct section of the customization menu by using either `SPC SPC customize-group` `org-faces`, or `SPC SPC customize-variable` and then choose some specific face.

After disabling the height attributes by 'unchecking' the box and saving the settings (press `C-x C-s` or the `Apply and Save` button), the configuration is added to the last section of your dotfile.

If you prefer to set it from your `user-config`, then you could use:

```lisp
  (with-eval-after-load 'org-faces
    (dolist (face '(org-document-title
                   org-level-1
                   org-level-2
                   org-level-3))
     (set-face-attribute face nil :height 1.0)))
```

Using a float for the height attribute makes Emacs use 'relative scaling' (see [section 'Face attributes' in the elisp reference](40.12.1 Face Attributes)).

Comment: I have tried it, saved it and there is no change ;( It writes: invalid face: org-document-title

Comment: Try adding `(require 'org-faces)` before the code above.

Comment: Haha, you are fast (thanks @NickD)... I was just adding this, I forgot to paste the correct version indeed. Better use `with-eval-after-load` as org (and also org-faces) are lazy loaded in Spacemacs.

Comment: Thanks it's working now ;)